# Want to update website content

Tags: update

I bought a licence for expression engine 7 years ago.  I now want to update my content on website and I cannot find expression engine to log in and make changes.  My website is www.keeinteriors.com can you help me?

I tried to log in and get forgotten password but none was sent to either email.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd go to www.yoursite.com/admin.php however this has been moved/renamed on your site. 
I'd FTP into the site and look at similar files in the root directory. You may find it's been renamed for security reasons.

Comment: I think she means she can't find the login credentials, not that she can't find the login panel...

Comment: Maybe she can log in to her EllisLab account and see which email address was used to create that account - chances are it'll be the same one that the forgotten password reminders are going to.